# help me to understand ANSEL register in PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, register, io

in new to PIC,this is bit confusing.

For switch ,usart we should clear ANSEL regsiter to make as digital IO so then only we can read 0 or 1 from that pin?,

data sheet says if we set particular pin as analog input and when read those pin it will return 0, So what is the need of ANSEL and when to enable

if im totally wrong please forgive and exlain me thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the ANSEL bit high for any pin for which you want to use the analog function. Otherwise set it low to use the digital function.

If you leave it low and need analog functionality it won't work at all.

If you leave it high, in this particular chip, the digital output will still work, however the pin will read zero. If this is a chip without the LAT function, a read-modify-write instruction will cause incorrect operation.

For example, you write 0xFF to the port and the ANSEL bit corresponding to bit 1 is 1, then all pins will indeed go high. However if I try to set bit 0 to 0 (a read-modify-write instruction - BCF in assembly language) so the port is expected to go to 0xFE then both bits 0 and 1 will go to zero (0xFC), because the instruction will write back **the value it read** from bit 1. This is usually very undesirable- it changes a bit that you had no intention of modifying.

Here is the machine cycle activity of a BCF instruction in a midrange PIC:

[image]

In cycle Q2 the register (a port in this case) is read, the desired bit is cleared, and then it is written back to the same register.

In the above example, the machine language instruction for clearing bit 0 of PORTA would be:

```
 BCF PORTA, 0
```

A compiler will add a layer on top of the machine language instructions, but unless they implement a shadow register (which slows things down so it would probably be an undesirable default) the RMW issue exists.

Comment: what is b and f in BCF b,f... im sorry im not familier with assembly language

Comment: f is the file register name. PORTA in the above example. b is the bit (0..7). So if you want to clear bit 2 in a register named STATUS you can use BCF STATUS,2

Comment: Yes, I think you understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on PICs, but it's common for pins to have different input circuitry depending on the selected function.

To retain an analog signal in the best way pins can be switched to an analog mode. You use this mode in conjunction with an analog to digital converter (to read more than just a 1 or 0) or digital to analog converter if you want to output a voltage other than VDD or VSS.

Also the signals get routed differently in your microcontroller depending on the selected function.

For any digital function on a pin you have to set it to digital mode (the normal mode).

Very helpful to understand how the particular microcontroller implements the pin functions are usually given in the datasheet somewhere (either in the GPIO part or an own section).

For a PIC12(L)F1571 it looks like [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001723D.pdf#page=109):
[image]

Which shows us, that the NOT ANSEL is used with an AND to the digital input of the pins. So if ANSEL is 1 the NOT will turn it to a 0 and the AND will result in a 0 regardless of the voltage at the input.

You might wonder why they do it like this. There are a few reasons which come to my mind (I do not design microcontrollers, so I don't know for sure):

- Applying an analog voltage to an unoptimized gate might cause high currents in the input stage if the voltage is in the middle of the logic levels
- An unoptimized gate might have an influence on the applied analog signal
- Applying an analog signal might cause erratic switching of the digital output (toggling very often) which might interfere with the digital peripherals and would also increase the current consumption